# Display Highcharts on web browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, highcharts

I have added different highcharts on a webpage. I am using Eclipse as IDE. When I want to see my webpage on Internet Explorer, everything is ok, all the charts are visible. But when I want to show the page on Mozilla Firefox / Google Chrome / Chromium ; I can see only linecharts and piecharts but no gauge chart.

This is code for gauge chart (visible on IE, invisible on other web browsers):

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >

  Highcharts.chart('chart-M', {

      chart: {
        backgroundColor: '#eeeeee',
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false,
        align: 'center',


      },

      title: {
        text: 'Are we better than last week?',
        align: 'center'
      },

      pane: {

        startAngle: -150,
        endAngle: 150,
        background: [{
          backgroundColor: {
            linearGradient: {
              x1: 0,
              y1: 0,
              x2: 0,
              y2: 1
            },
            stops: [
              [0, '#FFF'],
              [1, '#333']
            ]
          },
          borderWidth: 0,
          outerRadius: '109%'

        }, {
          backgroundColor: {
            linearGradient: {
              x1: 0,
              y1: 0,
              x2: 0,
              y2: 1
            },
            stops: [
              [0, '#333'],
              [1, '#FFF']
            ]
          },
          borderWidth: 0,
          outerRadius: '107%'
        }, {
          // default background
        }, {
          backgroundColor: '#DDD',
          borderWidth: 0,
          outerRadius: '105%',
          innerRadius: '103%'
        }]
      },

      // the value axis
      yAxis: {
        min: -100,
        max: 100,

        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        minorTickWidth: 1,
        minorTickLength: 10,
        minorTickPosition: 'inside',
        minorTickColor: '#666',

        tickPixelInterval: 30,
        tickWidth: 2,
        tickPosition: 'inside',
        tickLength: 10,
        tickColor: '#666',
        labels: {
          step: 2,
          rotation: 'auto'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'success / total sale'
        },
        plotBands: [{
          from: -100,
          to: 0,
          color: '#ff0000' // red 
        }, {
          from: 0,
          to: 100,
          color: '#008000' // green
        }]
      },

      series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [50],
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: 'success/total sale'
        }
      }]

    },
    // Add some life
    function(chart) {
      if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
        setInterval(function() {
          var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
            newVal,
            inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

          newVal = point.y + inc;
          if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
            newVal = point.y - inc;
          }

          point.update(newVal);

        }, 3000);
      }
    });

< /script>
```

What is the reason? Why can't I display this gauge chart on web browsers except Internet Explorer? 
Thank you for your help!
Thank you for your help!

Comment: follow this http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-solid/

Comment: Not sure why it does not work for you, added your code to a fiddle, and it works in chrome for me: [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0uc1g8b5/1/). So maybe it has something to do with the rest of the code you are exporting?

Comment: I created a demo using your code and tested it in Chrome (v59), Firefox (v54) and IE (v11) browsers and it works as expected in all of them. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/envzdzkh/. Could you try to recreate the problem and provide us with a working JSFiddle demo? Thanks.

Comment: @d_paul I tried to create fiddle but I cant see the results since it is connected to database. Do you have any other idea, why can't I see the gauge chart? I am using company computer; can it be related to administrator permission or something? Thank you.

Comment: @frusciante check, e.g with console.log(), if data even arrives and provide us with it. Maybe it is not adequately parsed.